# length along function

Tags: definite-integrals

I am no specialist in integration but I  would like to know what is the (arc?) length of the function (along the function) between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ where $ f(x) = \sqrt{(x^2+1)} $

I would like to see the deduction.

Comment: I think one usually writes $L=\int_a^bds$, where $ds$ satisfies $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$, so $ds =\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$, i.e., $ds=\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$. So plug in your function and compute the derivative etc. and try to evaluate. These sorts if integrals aren't always evaluable directly and may require numerical approximation.

Comment: I know you ask deep questions. I'm still searching for an upper bound. Then we can use pinch theorom to complete the "deduction." Yes, I think the def alone is inadequate.